# How to store data in 1096 columns

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, bar-chart

Main moto is to render a bar graph in my rails app (using highcharts).
I have a CSV (30MB) file of data (static data), with 1096 columns and 14000 rows. I want to be save it in database(MYSql). Initially i thought to save as an array.

Can you please tell me how it to be done (by keeping data performance in mind).
do you think creating 1096 columns will be good?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do I think creating 1096 columns will be good? Um, no.

Comment: @Strawberry yup! That's what i thought.  what would be the solution? like i have 3 years of data. each column represents each day. the datatype is float number. any clue?

Comment: Have a new row for each day

Answer (score 0):

1096 columns is pretty big. The question is, is the CSV highly denormalized? Do you have columns that represent the same data? If so, then you can create a table for each group of duplicate columns. This will decrease your column count but increase your table count.

MySQL allows for a max size of 65,535 bytes per row. This means that the average size of each column can be no larger than 59.79 bytes.

Breaking up your data into a single text column per row might work, but you won't be able to do any analysis on the data. However, if you convert it to JSON then you could store it in MongoDB or PostgreSQL databases.

There's no one right answer to your problem.

Comment: My data represents 3 year data, that's why i have 1096 columns. the datatype is a float number.

Answer (score 0):

Bad:

```
id Mon  Tue   Wed
 1  12    27    8
 2  19    26    4
 3  12  NULL    7
```

Good:

```
 id day value
  1 Mon    12
  1 Tue    27
  1 Wed     8
  2 Mon    19
  2 Tue    26
  2 Wed     4
  3 Mon    12
  3 Wed     7
```

This will lead to 3 columns and roughly 15 million rows.

3 columns and 15 million rows is going to be a lot easier to manage than 1096 columns and 14000 rows.

Comment: wow! that really got some ideas.  Thanks alot! will work on that.

Comment: Well, the idea is good. but the csv/excel is not able to handle 15 million rows. :(

Comment: A csv can certainly handle 15 million rows. Excel can't , but that just means you need a few more csvs

Answer (score 0):

1096 columns is certainly not a good idea, especially if the columns of the data are variable, and you would like to later process a file with different columns. Having a large number of fixed columns will turn out to be a very inflexible way to store the data.

If each column is a day, and each row is a measure of some sort, then you can try and store your data in a single table with 3 columns: date, measure, value. With such a table, there would be one row for each date-measure-value triplet (each "cell" in your csv file). This makes the table very flexible to addition of new days and/or measures.

However, if you would like to do any kind of analysis (including presenting the data as charts), you will face the problem of re-joining your data into the same tabular structure as your initial CSV. This can really be a performance bottleneck with very large datasets as it is solved in O(X * Y) time, where X is the number of rows, and Y is the number of columns. I don't have much experience with MySQL, but I have had good experiences in the past with PostgreSQL's [CROSSTAB](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/tablefunc.html) functionality to do this kind of restructuring.

This is just one approach, for which you will have to do quite a bit of experimentation to obtain optimal performance. You could look into NoSQL options as well. As has been said already, there is really no one right answer.